# ArXiv: ! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, arxiv

I'm trying to submit a generated zip from Overleaf to ArXiv, but the processing fails although the source seems correct.

The error message:

```
Highlighted AutoTeX Log:

[verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: *** Using TeX Live 2023 ***
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]: <main.bbl> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <main.tex> is of type 'PDFLATEX'.
[verbose]: <refs.bib> is of type 'BiBTeX'.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'main.tex'
[verbose]: arXiv Warning: user included plain hyperref directive.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running pdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2023/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/5109883/ && pdflatex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-05-05>
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latexsym.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/subcaption.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/ltcaption.sty)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty)

Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction.
`width' (433.62pt) is ignored.


Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction.
`height' (578.15999pt) is ignored.

) (/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file main.aux.
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ulasy.fd)

LaTeX Warning: No \author given.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmtt/m/n' undefined
(Font) using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead
(Font) for symbol `textbraceleft' on input line 49.


Package hyperref Warning: Ignoring empty anchor on input line 52.


Package hyperref Warning: Ignoring empty anchor on input line 53.

(./contents/introduction.tex

Package natbib Warning: Citation `deep-learning' on page 1 undefined on input l
ine 3.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `neural-operator' on page 1 undefined on input
line 3.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `fno' on page 1 undefined on input line 3.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `deeponet' on page 1 undefined on input line 3
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pangu-weather' on page 1 undefined on input l
ine 3.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `ml-accelerate-cfd' on page 1 undefined on inp
ut line 6.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pinn' on page 1 undefined on input line 6.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `metnet' on page 1 undefined on input line 6.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pangu-weather' on page 1 undefined on input l
ine 6.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `deeponet' on page 1 undefined on input line 9
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `fair-comparison-neural-operators' on page 1 u
ndefined on input line 9.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `neural-operator' on page 1 undefined on input
line 9.

[1{/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}])
(./contents/related-works.tex

Package natbib Warning: Citation `lattice-boltzmann' on page 2 undefined on inp
ut line 5.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `finite-difference-method' on page 2 undefined
on input line 7.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `finite-volume-method' on page 2 undefined on
input line 7.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `finite-element-method' on page 2 undefined on
input line 7.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `ritz-method' on page 2 undefined on input lin
e 7.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `galerkin-method' on page 2 undefined on input
line 7.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `spectral-method' on page 2 undefined on input
line 7.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `deep-learning' on page 2 undefined on input l
ine 11.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `prelu' on page 2 undefined on input line 11.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `resnet' on page 2 undefined on input line 11.



Package natbib Warning: Citation `gpt3' on page 2 undefined on input line 11.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `bert' on page 2 undefined on input line 11.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `lstm' on page 2 undefined on input line 11.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `gan' on page 2 undefined on input line 11.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `neocognitron' on page 2 undefined on input li
ne 11.

[2]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `image2image' on page 3 undefined on input lin
e 13.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `unet' on page 3 undefined on input line 13.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `latent-diffusion' on page 3 undefined on inpu
t line 13.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `cyclegan' on page 3 undefined on input line 1
3.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `resnet' on page 3 undefined on input line 13.



Package natbib Warning: Citation `unet' on page 3 undefined on input line 13.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pinn' on page 3 undefined on input line 22.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `cpinn' on page 3 undefined on input line 22.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `xpinn' on page 3 undefined on input line 22.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `apinn' on page 3 undefined on input line 22.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `can-pinn' on page 3 undefined on input line 2
2.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `gapinn' on page 3 undefined on input line 22.



Package natbib Warning: Citation `phygeonet' on page 3 undefined on input line
22.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `phycrnet' on page 3 undefined on input line 2
2.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pino' on page 3 undefined on input line 24.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `fno' on page 3 undefined on input line 24.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `lno' on page 3 undefined on input line 24.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `kno' on page 3 undefined on input line 24.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `deeponet' on page 3 undefined on input line 2
4.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pino' on page 3 undefined on input line 24.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `bayesian-deeponet' on page 3 undefined on inp
ut line 24.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `SVD-and-deeponet' on page 3 undefined on inpu
t line 24.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `long-time-prediction-deeponet' on page 3 unde
fined on input line 24.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `shift-deeponet' on page 3 undefined on input
line 24.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `physics-informed-deeponet' on page 3 undefine
d on input line 24.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `improved-deeponet' on page 3 undefined on inp
ut line 24.

) (./contents/cfdbench.tex

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./figs/examples.pdf): PDF inclusion: found PDF v
ersion <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed

Package natbib Warning: Citation `universal-approximation' on page 3 undefined
on input line 11.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pdebench' on page 3 undefined on input line 1
1.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `ns-dataset' on page 3 undefined on input line
11.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:fluid-examples' on page 3 undefined on input line
13.

[3 <./figs/examples.pdf>]

LaTeX Font Warning: Command \large invalid in math mode on input line 39.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <> not available
(Font) size <5> substituted on input line 47.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <0.7> not available
(Font) size <5> substituted on input line 47.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <0.5> not available
(Font) size <5> substituted on input line 47.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <> not available
(Font) size <5> substituted on input line 47.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <0.7> not available
(Font) size <5> substituted on input line 47.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <0.5> not available
(Font) size <5> substituted on input line 47.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <> not available
(Font) size <5> substituted on input line 47.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <0.7> not available
(Font) size <5> substituted on input line 47.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <0.5> not available
(Font) size <5> substituted on input line 47.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/n' in size <> not available
(Font) size <5> substituted on input line 47.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/n' in size <0.7> not available
(Font) size <5> substituted on input line 47.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/n' in size <0.5> not available
(Font) size <5> substituted on input line 47.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/lasy/m/n' in size <> not available
(Font) size <5> substituted on input line 47.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/lasy/m/n' in size <0.7> not available
(Font) size <5> substituted on input line 47.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/lasy/m/n' in size <0.5> not available
(Font) size <5> substituted on input line 47.



pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./figs/cavity_structure.pdf): PDF inclusion: fou
nd PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed

Package natbib Warning: Citation `cavity-background-coating' on page 4 undefine
d on input line 102.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `cavity-background-boundary' on page 4 undefin
ed on input line 102.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `cavity-background-verify' on page 4 undefined
on input line 102.

[4]

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./figs/tube_structure.pdf): PDF inclusion: found
PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./figs/dam_structure.pdf): PDF inclusion: found
PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed

Package natbib Warning: Citation `dam-background' on page 5 undefined on input
line 171.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `dam-numerical' on page 5 undefined on input l
ine 171.

[5 <./figs/cavity_structure.pdf>] [6 <./figs/tube_structure.pdf> <./figs/dam_st
ructure.pdf

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./figs/dam_structure.pdf): PDF inclusion: multip
le pdfs with page group included in a single page
>]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `cylinder-background-boundary' on page 7 undef
ined on input line 178.



pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./figs/cylinder_structure.pdf): PDF inclusion: f
ound PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed

Overfull \hbox (117.53899pt too wide) detected at line 204
[]

Overfull \hbox (117.53899pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 204--205
[]$[]$|

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 208--209
[]$\OML/cmm/m/it/10.95 x[]; y[]; y[] \OMS/cmtt/m/n/10.95 2

LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab:dataset-breakdown' on page 7 undefined on input l
ine 217.

[7] [8 <./figs/cylinder_structure.pdf>]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:residuals' on page 9 undefined on input line 264.




pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./figs/residuals.pdf): PDF inclusion: found PDF
version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed
) (./contents/experiments.tex [9 <./figs/residuals.pdf>]
(./contents/table-model-overview.tex

LaTeX Warning: No positions in optional float specifier.
Default added (so using `tbp') on input line 2.


Overfull \hbox (21.41017pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 7--73
[][]
)

Package natbib Warning: Citation `deeponet' on page 10 undefined on input line
84.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab:model-overview' on page 10 undefined on input lin
e 84.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:network-io' on page 10 undefined on input line 84
.

[10] [11 <./figs/network-io.pdf>]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:networks-structure' on page 12 undefined on input
line 101.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pinn' on page 12 undefined on input line 101.



Package natbib Warning: Citation `deeponet' on page 12 undefined on input line
113.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:networks-structure' on page 12 undefined on input
line 119.

[12 <./figs/networks-structure.pdf>]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `pinn' on page 13 undefined on input line 139.



LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:networks-structure' on page 13 undefined on input
line 139.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:networks-structure' on page 13 undefined on input
line 144.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `edeeponet' on page 13 undefined on input line
160.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:networks-structure' on page 13 undefined on input
line 171.


Overfull \hbox (13.31058pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 184--185
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 We also ex-per-i-mented with CNN as the fea-ture ex-trac-tor
for the in-put field called \OT1/cmr/bx/n/10.95 Auto-DeepONetCNN\OT1/cmr/m/n/1
0.95 .
[13]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `resnet' on page 14 undefined on input line 19
3.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `unet' on page 14 undefined on input line 205.



LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:networks-structure' on page 14 undefined on input
line 205.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:networks-structure' on page 14 undefined on input
line 220.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `fno' on page 14 undefined on input line 232.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:networks-structure' on page 14 undefined on input
line 232.

[14]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `fno' on page 15 undefined on input line 244.

[15]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:results' on page 16 undefined on input line 281.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:appendix-hyperparameter' on page 16 undefined on
input line 287.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab:resnet-result' on page 16 undefined on input line
291.

(./contents/table-resnet-result.tex

LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:results' on page 16 undefined on input line 2.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:results' on page 16 undefined on input line 2.


LaTeX Warning: `!h' float specifier changed to `!ht'.

)) (./contents/results.tex

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./figs/results_part1.pdf): PDF inclusion: found
PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./figs/results_part2.pdf): PDF inclusion: found
PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed
[16] [17 <./figs/results_part1.pdf>] [18 <./figs/results_part2.pdf>]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:results-velocity-1' on page 19 undefined on input
line 30.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:results-velocity-2' on page 19 undefined on input
line 30.

[19 <./figs/bars.pdf>] (./contents/table-non-auto-results.tex
Overfull \hbox (5.5074pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 61--208
[][]
)

LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab:non-auto-results' on page 20 undefined on input l
ine 40.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `deeponet' on page 20 undefined on input line
40.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:result-summary' on page 20 undefined on input lin
e 47.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab:autoregressive-results' on page 20 undefined on i
nput line 47.

[20]

LaTeX Warning: `h' float specifier changed to `ht'.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pangu-weather' on page 21 undefined on input
line 91.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:result-temporal-extrapolation' on page 21 undefin
ed on input line 93.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pangu-weather' on page 21 undefined on input
line 97.

(./contents/table-computational-cost.tex [21]

LaTeX Warning: `h' float specifier changed to `ht'.

)

Package natbib Warning: Citation `fno' on page 22 undefined on input line 105.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `deeponet' on page 22 undefined on input line
105.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pangu-weather' on page 22 undefined on input
line 105.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pinn' on page 22 undefined on input line 105.



LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab:result-computational-cost' on page 22 undefined o
n input line 107.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:deeponet' on page 22 undefined on input line 109.


[22 <./figs/multistep_infer_cavity.pdf> <./figs/multistep_infer_tube.pdf> <./fi
gs/multistep_infer_dam.pdf> <./figs/multistep_infer_cylinder.pdf>])
(./contents/conclusion.tex (./contents/table-auto-results.tex [23]
Overfull \hbox (13.8392pt too wide) in alignment at lines 6--253
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
[24] [25])) (./main.bbl [26] [27] [28]) [29] (./contents/appendix.tex

LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab:math-notations' on page 30 undefined on input lin
e 5.


Underfull \hbox (badness 4673) in paragraph at lines 26--27
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 The work-ing con-di-tion pa-ram-e-ters,

Package natbib Warning: Citation `gelu' on page 30 undefined on input line 49.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `pinn' on page 30 undefined on input line 49.

[30]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:deeponet-hyperparameters' on page 31 undefined on
input line 53.

[31 <./figs/hyper_deeponet.png>]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:fno-hyperparameters' on page 32 undefined on inpu
t line 81.

[32 <./figs/hyper_unet.png>])

Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.

[33 <./figs/hyper_fno.png>] (./main.aux

Package natbib Warning: Citation(s) may have changed.
(natbib) Rerun to get citations correct.


! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

(natbib) Press <return> to continue in numerical citation style.


See the natbib package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...

l.242 ...and\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers

?
! Emergency stop.
...

l.242 ...and\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'main.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.aux' (1694581442 >= 1694581441)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.out' (1694581442 >= 1694581441)
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2023/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/5109883/ && tex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=tex)
(./main.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \pdfoutput
=1
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1

No pages of output.
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: tex 'main.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'main.tex'
[error]: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.
*** AutoTeX ABORTING ***

[verbose]: AutoTeX returned error: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.

[verbose]: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[verbose]: Error running AutoTeX process:
```

Comment: It would seem that `natbib` rules should be read before submitting, or at least the accepted styles. Necessary files to create the fonts either need to be included or make another choice of fonts in any basic package. Might be helpful to produce bland with ArXiv and fancy with a publisher.

Comment: Didn't you get an error from natbib in overleaf?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did not get any errors from natbib in Overleaf. I honestly do not think natbib is the reason for the failure.

Comment: `! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.` is clearly an error related to natbib.

Comment: add `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` to your preamble.

Comment: I'm receiving the same error, both before and after @Jake 's suggestion. What other suggestions do people have?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer, you should contact arXiv support with your submission-ID if this didn’t solve your issue.